# Changing deep copy value using Spread operator

Tags: reactjs

I have tried to change the value of `DataContext` so i tried like this:

```js
const changeSecondLabel = index => value => {
    setDataContext(dataContext =>
      dataContext.map((data, i) =>
        i === index
          ? {
              ...data,
              datasets: [{ ...data.datasets.label, label: value }],
            }
          : data
      )
    );
  };
```

## this is `DataContext`

```js
 const [DataContext, setDataContext] = useState([
    {
      labels: defaultLabels,
      datasets: [
        {
          label: "dataSetting",
          data: defaultDatas,
          backgroundColor: defaultBackgroundColor,
        },
      ],
    }, ///
    {
      labels: defaultLabels,
      datasets: [
        {
          label: "dataSetting",
          data: defaultDatas,
          backgroundColor: defaultBackgroundColor,
        },
      ],
    }, ///
    {
      labels: defaultLabels,
      datasets: [
        {
          label: "dataSetting",
          data: defaultDatas,
          backgroundColor: defaultBackgroundColor,
        },
      ],
    }, ///....
```

However, whenever I change the `label` to value. then, the `DataContext`  `datasets` is disappeared .
I assume that deep copying `datasets` is not the way i should do ,
So i want to know how to fix it .

Thank you in advance !

Comment: You can replace this `...data.datasets.label` with `...data.datasets` since that contains the rest of the data of each `dataset`

Comment: Thank you for answering , Do you mean `{ ...data,  ...data.datasets,  datasets: [{...data.datasets.label, label: value }],   }` like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to replicate the code structure you have provided and came up with a solution. You cannot directly apply the rest operator to the dataset since it is an array and you are planning to apply the rest operator to each elements inside the dataset.

Hence,I mapped the `datasets` and applied the deep level rest operator.

```js
let dataSet = [
  {
    labels: "One",
    datasets: [
      {
        label: "dataSetting",
        data: "defaultDatas",
        backgroundColor: "defaultBackgroundColor",
      },
    ],
  },{
    labels: "Two",
    datasets: [
      {
        label: "TwodataSetting",
        data: "TwodefaultDatas",
        backgroundColor: "TwodefaultBackgroundColor",
      },
    ],
  },{
    labels: "Three",
    datasets: [
      {
        label: "ThreedataSetting",
        data: "ThreedefaultDatas",
        backgroundColor: "ThreedefaultBackgroundColor",
      },
    ],
  }, 
];


const changeSecondLabel = index => value => {
    debugger;
  dataSet = dataSet.map((data, i) =>
    i === index
      ? {
          ...data,
          datasets: data.datasets.map(set => {return {...set, label: value}}),
        }
      : data
  )
};

changeSecondLabel(1)("New Value");
console.log(dataSet);
```

Comment: Oh thank you so much !! this is awesome ! i got an issue with my code for another reason haha not because of your answer . i need to fix the problem ! Thank You !!